# Serilog's enricher does not log properties

Tags: serilog

I have ASP.NET MVC application and im using Serilog for logging purpose. I have implemented serilog's enricher to log user's username for every log entry

```cs
public class HttpContextEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    LogEventProperty _cachedProperty;

    public const string EnvironmentUserNamePropertyName = "MyUserName";

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
            return;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity == null)
            return;

        _cachedProperty = _cachedProperty ?? propertyFactory.CreateProperty(EnvironmentUserNamePropertyName, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_cachedProperty);
    }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```cs
public static class HttpContextLoggerConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithUserName(
        this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        if (enrichmentConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrichmentConfiguration));
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With<HttpContextEnricher>();
    }
}
```

**Configured it at application start**

```cs
     Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithUserName()                       
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();
```

Here is my app settings

```xml
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Information" />
<add key="serilog:using:EventLog" value="Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog.source" value="MySource" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog.manageEventSource" value="false" />
```

This is how i am logging

```cs
Log.Information("Some information messaage");
```

I am using [WindowsEvent Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog). When i execute the application i see the message is getting logged in the windows's event source, however the log does not have `MyUserName` property.

I am not sure what i am missing here?

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in your `Enrich()` method?

Comment: I see it returns the valid user name

Comment: Ah, it may just be that the event log sink doesn't list all properties in the event? You could try writing out e.g. JSON to a file, and see whether the properties are in there: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact#getting-started -- HTH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to explicitly set UserName in outputTemplate so that it can write to sink.

```xml
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog.outputTemplate" value="[{Level}]{NewLine}{Timestamp:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}{NewLine}UserName:{MyUserName}{NewLine}Message:{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
```